# Changing UINavigationBar height in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to change the height of the UINavigationBar in my NavigationController which precedes my UITableViewController in my table view application. I did this successfully by using the following code in ViewDidLoad of my TableViewController:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = 
    CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 100.0);
```

The problem now is that the table does not move down but is covered with the newly extended navigation bar - the first line of it at least.

[image: Looks like this]

Any ideas how I could reposition the top of the table downward or am I not resizing the navigation bar correctly?

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: I would recommendate you to subclass the UINavigationController and resize it in layoutsubviews to get the effect you desire. If you use the code in viewdidload then it wont autoresize the tableview below correctly. The TableView doesn't know that it should move down more pixels.

Comment: Or just offset the frame of the TableView. `self.tableView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.tableview.frame,0,kOffsetAmount);` and adjust the height accordingly (if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could set the `.prompt` of the navigationbar to @" " ... not the most elegant solution and not very flexible but it works